# When is the delta used in a member function pointer on GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, pointer-to-member

I was reading the article [Member Function Pointers and the Fastest Possible C++ Delegates](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) from Don Clugston and was experimenting with this stuff myself and was not able to reproduce a case correctly.

Of course, the code from Don Clugston is undefined behaviour.

This is specifically about GCC's representation of member function pointers.

Here's a code snippet from the article about the GCC member function representation (copied as is from the article, not actual code, don't even compile):

> ```
> // GNU g++ uses a tricky space optimisation, also adopted by IBM's VisualAge and XLC.
> struct GnuMFP {
>    union {
>      CODEPTR funcadr;    // always even
>      int vtable_index_2; //  = vindex*2+1, always odd
>    };
>    int delta;
> };
> adjustedthis = this + delta
> if (funcadr & 1) CALL (* ( *delta + (vindex+1)/2) + 4)
> else CALL funcadr
> ```

Of course, the standard says nothing about this. Also, GCC ABI might have changed a lot since the article was written. However, I'm not interested in the standard or defined behaviour. I am interested in the current ABI and what the compiler do.

The problem is that I haven't been able to produce a member function pointer that fills the `delta` value for me to experiment with it.

I assumed something similar to `delta` still exist since the size of a member function pointer is still the size of two pointer. Also, according to my observations, the vtable index trick still apply today.

Here's what I tried:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void print_pointer(auto const ptr) {
    alignas(alignof(ptr)) std::byte memory[sizeof(ptr)];
    std::memcpy(memory, std::addressof(ptr), sizeof(ptr));

    auto until_newline = int{8};
    for (auto const b : memory) {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(b);
        if (--until_newline == 0) {
            until_newline = 8;
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
}

// No inheritance, simplest possible
namespace test1 {
    struct S {
        char a;
        void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
}

// Simple inheritance, non polymorphic
namespace test2 {
    struct B1 { char a; };
    struct S : B1 {
        char a;
        void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
}

// Multiple inheritance, non polymorphic
namespace test3 {
    struct B1 { char a; };
    struct B2 { char a; };
    struct S : B1, B2 {
        char a;
        void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
}

// Multiple inheritance, non polymorphic, function in the middle
namespace test4 {
    struct B1 { char a; };
    struct B2 {
        char a;
        void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
    struct S : B1, B2 { char a; };
}

// Simple inheritance, polymorphic
namespace test5 {
    struct B1 {
        char a;
        virtual void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
    struct S : B1 {
        void method() const& override {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
}

// Multiple inheritance, polymorphic, one base only
namespace test6 {
    struct B1 {
        char a;
        virtual void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
    struct B2 {
        char a;
    };
    struct S : B1, B2 {
        void method() const& override {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
}

// Multiple inheritance, polymorphic, two base
namespace test7 {
    struct B1 {
        char a;
        virtual void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
    struct B2 {
        char a;
        virtual void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
    struct S : B1, B2 {
        void method() const& override {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
}

// Simple virtual inheritance, non polymorphic
namespace test8 {
    struct B1 { char a; };
    struct S : virtual B1 {
        void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
}

// Simple virtual inheritance, polymorphic
namespace test9 {
    struct B1 {
        char a;
        virtual void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
    struct S : virtual B1 {
        void method() const& override {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
}

// Multiple with one virtual inheritance, one polymorphic
namespace test10 {
    struct B1 {
        char a;
        virtual void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
    struct B2 {
        char a;
    };
    struct S : B1, virtual B2 {
        void method() const& override {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
}

// Multiple with both virtual inheritance, both polymorphic
namespace test11 {
    struct B1 {
        char a;
        virtual void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
    struct B2 {
        char a;
        virtual void method() const& {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
    struct S : virtual B1, virtual B2 {
        void method() const& override {
            std::cout << "test1 S";
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    print_pointer(&test1::S::method);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_pointer(&test2::S::method);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_pointer(&test3::S::method);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_pointer(&test4::S::method);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_pointer(&test5::S::method);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_pointer(&test6::S::method);
    print_pointer(&test6::B1::method);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_pointer(&test7::S::method);
    print_pointer(&test7::B1::method);
    print_pointer(&test7::B2::method);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_pointer(&test8::S::method);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_pointer(&test9::S::method);
    print_pointer(&test9::B1::method);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_pointer(&test10::S::method);
    print_pointer(&test10::B1::method);
    std::cout << '\n';
    print_pointer(&test11::S::method);
    print_pointer(&test11::B1::method);
    print_pointer(&test11::B2::method);
}
```

In all of my example, the last 8 byte of the member function pointer is `0000000000000000`

Here's the complete output:

```
b013400000000000 0000000000000000 

f013400000000000 0000000000000000 

3014400000000000 0000000000000000 

d013400000000000 0000000000000000 

0100000000000000 0000000000000000 

0100000000000000 0000000000000000 
0100000000000000 0000000000000000 

0100000000000000 0000000000000000 
0100000000000000 0000000000000000 
0100000000000000 0000000000000000 

1014400000000000 0000000000000000 

0100000000000000 0000000000000000 
0100000000000000 0000000000000000 

0100000000000000 0000000000000000 
0100000000000000 0000000000000000 

0100000000000000 0000000000000000 
0100000000000000 0000000000000000 
0100000000000000 0000000000000000
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/bMsjs9eEh)

How can I produce a member function pointer with a non zero delta on GCC?

Comment: That article you've linked to is hardly "famous".   In any event, it dates from 2005, and the ABI (Application Binary Interface) used by gcc has changed more than once since then (e.g. there was a change of ABI to support C++11).   Among other things, choice of ABI will affect the layout of C++ struct/class types, the layout of vtable, and how that vtable is reached from an instance of each struct/class type.   And the code you show makes specific assumptions about such things.

Comment: This line: `if (funcadr & 1) CALL (* ( *delta + (vindex+1)/2) + 4)` is trying to type-alias through a `union` which is Undefined Behaviour according to the C++ Standard.  Given the comment from @Peter above regarding the date of the article you will need to check if GCC still supports this as an extension (if it ever did).

Comment: @Peter okay, removed the "famous". I'm still curious about what GCC generates and why.

Comment: @RichardCritten I clarified that the sample from the article is not really actual code, but merely an example to explain how the compiler may generate a call using a MFP. Tell me if you need any other clarifications. Also, I don't intend to use disabled unions member, there are better ways today, including `std::bit_cast`.

Comment: @RichardCritten - The line is done **by the implementation**, and it can define and rely on whatever behavior it wants. It knows what it does.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot      What gcc generates for layout of classes and virtual function tables is specified by the ABI it supports.    That code you've shown may have worked with versions of gcc dating from 2005 or earlier.  But since the ABI has changed there is no guarantee that code will work in later versions of gcc.    The code formally has undefined behaviour as Richard Critten noted, so there is no requirement in the standard that it do anything in particular - the compiler can do what it likes.

Comment: @Peter Of course. I'm not interested by what the standard says, I'm interested by what the compiler do under its current ABI implementation.

Comment: @Peter I added a paragraph in the question that clarify this. Please if anything is still unclear, let me know.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hGqPE5oPx You have to construct a case where the method expects a different `this`. If you just use the expression to build the mfp, you end up with a type where you see the original class the function has been defined in - for this, no adjustment to `this` is necessary (type here: `void(test4::B2::*)()const&`). Comparison: https://godbolt.org/z/Tjjve67dY

Comment: @dyp Oh! I was looking for that example. It seem to be related to casting the pointer, not the classes themselfves. Thank you! If you write an answer with an explanation, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Just [read the ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#member-function-pointers). It's all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the GCC code, so I'm just doing some guesswork and hypotheses.

The delta is used to adjust the `this` pointer. So we have to construct a case where:

```cpp
MyClass* pThis = ...;
MemberFunctionPointer mfp = ...;
(pThis->*mfp)(); // must adjust this := pThis + delta
```

Why would `this` (the this pointer inside the member function) be different from `pThis`? This can happen if we call a member function *from a different class*:

```cpp
struct B1
{
    char c;
};

struct B2
{
    char d;
    void memfun();
};

struct S : B1, B2
{
    void direct();
};
```

When you do something like

```cpp
B2 b2;
b2.memfun();
```

Then we don't have to adjust the `this` pointer, `this := &b2`. In other words, `B2::memfun` expects the `this` pointer to point to the (sub)object `B2`.

The subobject `B2` inside an object of type `S` is offset by `B1`. Therefore, when we write

```cpp
S s;
s.memfun();
```

the compiler has to adjust the address from `&s` to `&s.d` effectively - it applies a delta.

---

We can now construct the example that generates a delta in the member function pointer:

```cpp
using Smfp = void(S::*)();
Smfp m = &S::memfun; // it's really B2::memfun!

S s;
(s.*m)(); // we're calling B2::memfun, therefore we need to adjust this := &s + delta == &s.d
```

Note that we can write

```cpp
m = &S::direct;
(s.*m)(); // calls S::direct, no adjustment, this := &s
```

this explains why we need to store the delta as part of the member function pointer.

---

A slight pitfall is the class type used for the member function pointer:

```cpp
using B2mfp = void(B2::*)();
B2mfp x = &B2::memfun; // x has no delta!

B2 b;
(b.*x)(); // no need to adjust, this := &b
```

The type of `&S::memfun` is actually `void(B2::*)()` because that's how inheritance of member functions works: the lookup first searches `S` and then its bases. There's no dedicated `S::memfun` (no code for it), there's really only `B2::memfun` which we can also find with the name/alias `S::memfun`.